# What's the difinition of "recent" for Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, real-time-updates

I'm developing an application using Instagram API. I'm subscribed to a tag real-time update, but I've seen that when a put the hashtag to an old picture and ask for the "recent" media with that tag I get the old picture but, after a lot of others... So, what's the definition of "recent" for Instagram API? Is there any way to get just the new media that really changed (or were added), let's say, after "my last update notification"?

Comment: I've only got a little experience with tags but you can use the MAX_TAG_ID parameter to specify that you want posts made after that post. 

I know posts can be tagged retroactively by the user so I'm not sure whether the recent tags endpoint gives you results in the order they were posted or the order they were tagged

Comment: As posts can be tagged retroactively I can't use the MAX_TAG_ID because, based on what I've seen, results are given in the order they were posted, not in the order they were tagged... Anyway, thanks for answering!